# Warning for assignment in an if statement?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way I can get a warning when I'm assigning a variable instead of checking equality? There have been many times where I have accidentally assigned, rather than compared, and it would be great to have a warning!

Is there a way Xcode can warn me without having to change coding styles to:

```
if (YES == aVariable) {...}
```

Comment: Doesn't clang already do that by default?

Comment: ya i get it by default as well

Comment: @nmock And please, improve it by not deleting your question after you get a valid answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode already warns you if you use `=` instead of `==` in an `if` statement in most cases.  If you're not getting the warning, tell us what version of Xcode you're using, how old your project is, and what build settings you have changed from their defaults.

My test: I created a brand new iOS app in Xcode 4.5.2 and didn't change any build settings.  I just added a little code to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to trigger the warning.  Here it is:

[image: Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses]

You can disable the warning by setting the compiler's `-Wno-parentheses` flag (but why would you want to?).  You can suppress the warning in a particular case by adding an extra set of parentheses around the assignment:

```
if ((x = 7)) {
```

There are two cases where you don't get the warning by default.  First, in an `init` method, you can assign to `self`, like this:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {     // no warning by default
    ...
```

Second, in any context, you can assign the result of the `nextObject` selector, like this:

```
while (object = [enumerator nextObject]) {    // no warning by default
```

You can enable warnings in these cases by setting the compiler's `-Widiomatic-parentheses` flag.

Comment: @robmayoff Using Xcode Version 4.5 (4G182), I was confused because I never encountered these errors as a result of assignment before, but recently, it hasn't been catching them. I have tried adding `-Widiomatic-parentheses` to both the "Other Linker Flags" as well as "Warning Linker Flags" to no avail.

Comment: These aren't linker flags.  Try adding `-Wparentheses` to the “Other Warning Flags” setting under the “Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - Warnings - All languages” section of your Build Settings.  Also make sure the “Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C” setting (under the “Build Options” section) is set to “Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2”, not “LLVM GCC 4.2”.

Comment: You can use the search box under the Build Settings tab to find those settings more easily.

Comment: @robmayoff made these changes, however, it's still not producing the warning. “Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1” is the only option for Xcode 4.5. I will try updating to the latest Xcode, but do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I wonder if perhaps he unknowningly has the flag -Wno-parentheses set, which is overriding -Wparentheses. It would help if you could paste the compile command. Go into the Log Navigator, click "Compile [file].m" and then click the disclosure button on the far right to get the arguments fed to the compiler. Paste on pastie or gist.

Comment: @nm6963 Actually Compiler 4.2 isn't part of a public release of Xcode yet, so I shouldn't have mentioned it. :)  Compiler 4.1 produces the warnings for me.

Comment: those compiler flags should result in warnings on assignments in conditionals with no parentheses, very odd.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler flag `Wparentheses` should do the trick. It will force you to place parentheses around assignments in a conditional in order to compile. Clang has this flag set by default.

Comment: The `-Widiomatic-parentheses` flag only affects the warning on assignments to `self` in an `init` method, and assignments using the return value of the `nextObject` selector.  See the `Sema::DiagnoseAssignmentAsCondition` function in [SemaExpr.cpp](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Sema/SemaExpr.cpp?revision=166496&view=markup).

Comment: you are correct, the correct flag would be Wparentheses, I will update my answer to reflect that. Thanks

Comment: I didn't know about the idiomatic parentheses flag until I saw your answer, so thanks for teaching me something new. :)

Comment: interesting that they have a case for something like `-nextObject`, which appears to be extremely API-specific.

Comment: My guess is Apple uses that idiom a lot internally… ;^)